# react-zoom-pan-pinch (setScale)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This library provides us to use `<TransformWrapper>` which has a lot of methods.
But I want to use method - `setScale` and mine problem is I can not set position for zoom

```
  <TransformWrapper
      defaultScale={1}
      options={{ minScale: 1, maxScale: 4 }}
      zoomIn={{ step: 5 }}
      zoomOut={{ step: 5 }}
      wheel={{ step: 35, limitsOnWheel: true }}
      doubleClick={{ disabled: true }}
      pan={{ disabled: isPan, paddingSize: 0 }}
    >
      {({ scale, maxScale, zoomIn, zoomOut, setScale }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <TransformComponent>
            ...
          </TransformComponent>
          <MySlider
            curScale={scale}
            maxScale={maxScale}
            zoomIn={zoomIn}
            zoomOut={zoomOut}
            setScale={setScale} />
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </TransformWrapper>
```

When I am using this method its zooming to left-top corner but I want to zoom to center of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Different Panzoom plugins work differently. You can still try using the **`defaultPositionX`** and **`defaultPositionY`** properties for this plugin.

By default, they have **NULL** values.

Comment: I setted this properties and it still zooming to the left-top corner

Comment: Nikita, I tried to connect this plugin to my project, it does not work at all

Comment: Also, for positionX, Y, defaultPositionX, Y
I have to change props: 
limitToBounds?: boolean;
centerContent?: boolean;
limitToWrapper?: boolean;

But I dont need in it....

Comment: check out more of these plugins
https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom
https://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/jQuery-Plugin-For-Panning-Zooming-Any-Elements-panzoom.html